# Show background image on print view but hide on web browser view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, printing

I would like to show background image on print version and not in web version. I have the following code.

```
.page_1_print_background{
        display: none;  
    }

@media print{
.page_1_print_background{
        display: block; 
        background:transparent url('/img/page_1_background_image1.png');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        object-fit: cover;     
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; 
        color-adjust: exact !important;                
    }
}
```

From the above code in print version I cannot view background image even if I added background image in print css.

I have forced background image to print css still background image is not showing in print version.

Comment: Have you made sure that you’ve enabled printing backgrounds in the print dialog?

Comment: Yes, all other background images are printing in print view except this.

Comment: I would like to show the background image on print version, but hide the same background image on web browser view.